# warning in kernel module: expected ‘struct rwlock_t *’ but argument is of type ‘struct rwlock_t *’

Tags: linux-kernel, spinlock

I get a strange compiler warning when i use the reader-writer spinlock as below,

***defined in a.c***

```
struct rwloct_t  rwspinlock.
rwlock_init(&rwspinlock);
```

***using in b.c by declaring***

```
extern struct rwloct_t  rwspinlock
```

So, in ***b.c*** whenever i call lock or unlock, eg.`read_rwlock(&rwspinlock)`  i get the below warning.

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘_raw_read_lock_bh’ from incompatible pointer type
/home/dev/data/linux/linux/include/linux/rwlock_api_smp.h:20: note: expected ‘struct rwlock_t *’ but argument is of type ‘struct rwlock_t *’
```

Then, I changed as below,
***defined in a.c***

```
struct rwloct_t  rwspinlock.
rwlock_init(&rwspinlock);
```

***declared in a.h***

```
 extern struct rwloct_t  rwspinlock
```

included in b.c as,

```
#include "a.h"
```

Now there is no compilation warning. However, i'm unclear how!.
Can anybody explain, what exactly happened ?

Comment: Compiler bug??  You may want to flag your question and ask a mod to migrate it over to Stack Overflow if you don't get an answer fairly soon

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your `rwloct_t` is already defined (`typedef`) as a struct (here the `_t` suffix)?

If so you don't need to use struct again:

`rwloct_t  rwspinlock;`

`extern rwloct_t  rwspinlock;`

Why it work within `.h` and not `.c`? I don't know, but you may try to precompile both with `gcc` and the option `-E` and see if there's some difference, else I guess is some compiler internal reason.

Comment: I tried adding -E to EXTRA_CFLAGS in my module compilation Makefile, but it throws error"make: invalid option -- 'E'"

Comment: Try to use it manually with a single .c file from the command line not in the Makefile